# PHP, imagecreate, imagecreatetruecolor, imagecopy, imagecopymerge

Tags: php, gd

(1) imagecreate

(2) imagecreatetruecolor

(3) imagecopy

(4) imagecopymerge

I use above PHP function and get confused.

First I prepare two png files...

1.png http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/1.png

A QRcode with transparent background and black dot, I create it by these code (only keypoint, not all).

```
$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$color1 = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imageColorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color1);
...
imagepng($image, $filename);
```

2.png http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/2.png

I make a png and use a color to fill its background by MS paint.

Prepare done. Then the code is

```
<?php
//use imagecreate or imagecreatetruecolor
$image = imagecreate(50, 50);
//$image = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);

//save the alpha channel
imagesavealpha($image, true);

//alphablending set false, then transparent color can cover the canvas
imagealphablending($image, false);

//take a transparent color and fill it
imagefill($image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127));

//draw the ellipse
imagefilledellipse($image, 15, 15, 30, 30, imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0));

imagepng($image, '3.png');

imagedestroy($image);

//merge image
$im_background = imagecreatefrompng('1.png');
$im_foreground = imagecreatefrompng('3.png');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('3.png');

//use imagecopy or imagecopymerge
imagecopy($im_background, $im_foreground, (int)35, (int)35, 0, 0, $width, $height);
//imagecopymerge($im_background, $im_foreground, (int)35, (int)35, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);

imagepng($im_background, 'x-x.png');

imagedestroy($im_background);
imagedestroy($im_foreground);
```

The code make 3.png like this www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/3.png

Now if I use

1.png + imagecreate + imagecopy will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/4-1.png

1.png + imagecreate + imagecopymerge will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/4-2.png

1.png + imagecreatetruecolor + imagecopy will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/4-3.png

1.png + imagecreatetruecolor + imagecopymerge will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/4-4.png

2.png + imagecreate + imagecopy will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/5-1.png

2.png + imagecreate + imagecopymerge will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/5-2.png

2.png + imagecreatetruecolor + imagecopy will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/5-3.png

2.png + imagecreatetruecolor + imagecopymerge will get http://www.capbite.com/subfolder/lion/test/5-4.png

It is hard to describe the image that made by different ways, so I paste the link about the images, but my reputation is not enough to post more links or images... -- *Edited by Niet ;)*

My question is, just the 3.png, it has a transparent background, even use different create function, but when it copy to another image which I created or by MS paint, the result is I meet.

What's different between imagecreate & imagecreatetruecolor make 4-1.png and 4-3.png ?

What's different between imagecopy & imagecopymerge(even pct set 100) make 4-3.png and 4-4.png ?

What's different between the images which I created or by MS paint make 4-3.png and 5-3.png ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All the capbite.com links are dead, which really devalues this question.  Seems like it could be way useful to others, but not in this form.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `imagecreate`, not `imagecreatetruecolor`.

When using `imagecreate`, the first colour you define will be the background colour that fills the entire canvas. This will usually be your "transparent" colour, however it is generally better (read: more efficient in the file) to do it this way:

```
imagecolortransparent($img, imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 255));
```

In this way, you aren't using an alpha channel, you're just telling it "anything I draw in bright pink will be transparent" - this is how transparency works in GIF images, by the way, and it's also the "traditional" way to do it, way back on old games from many many years ago!

Using `imagecreate`-generated images, copying works a *lot* easier, because GD knows exactly what colour is "transparent" and therefore shouldn't be copied on to the target. When using `imagecreatetruecolor`, then you get into the complicated and messy business of compositing...

I hope this helps you out. GD can be a tricky beast to master, but once you know the basics you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for sharing experiences and help!